# React | Virtual DOM element click event not triggering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, virtual-dom

I'm using [Ant Design](https://ant.design/) and [React js](https://reactjs.org/) for my Project.

**Problem**

I have a button in Popover and having click event for that button. The problem is button click event is not triggering.

**JS Code**

```
const content = (
  <div className="RecurringPopover"> 
    <button onClick={this.handleClick}> Popover Button </button> 
  </div>
);
```

**Full Code with scenario in** [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ql4wwo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined `content` outside the class and then supplying `this.handleClick` as a click handler to it. However outside class, `this` does not point to the `class`. You should define `content` inside `class` and use `this.content` to access that.

```
handleClick() {
      alert('test');
    }
// put it inside class
 content = (
  <div className="RecurringPopover"> 
    <button onClick={this.handleClick}> Popover Button </button> 
  </div>
);
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Row>
          <Col span={12}>      
          // Use this.content instead of just content
          <Popover content={this.content} title="Title">
            <span type="primary">Hover me (Popover Button)</span>
```

Comment: Dont use `const` inside class. Look at my code in answer. It is `content = (...`

Comment: What is the error now? The code in the answer is working.

Comment: @MariaJeysinghAnbu Look at my answer. I said use `this.content` instead of just `content`.  `<Popover content={this.content} title="Title">`

Answer (score 0):

Just bring the '`content`' to inside the class, and pass it to component via '`this.content`', it will work.